# Mysql : One user but all informations link to that user

Tags: mysql, join

So I have this Query:

```
SELECT 
users.id,
users.lastname,
users.firstname,
progressions.id,
progressions.axis,
progressions.topic_id
FROM `progressions`
JOIN topics on topics.id = progressions.topic_id
JOIN criteria on criteria.id = topics.criteria_id
JOIN cards on cards.id = criteria.card_id
JOIN users on users.id = cards.user_id;
```

And it gives me this : [image]

So I would like to know how can I have still all my progression.id + progressions.axis + progressions.topic_id rows but have only ONE user row?

Comment: make a full [mre] please

Comment: @nbk which tool can I use to reproduce this ?

Comment: `Group by` the userid and `group_concat` the fields that have multiple data points.

Comment: @user3783243 Might be the good way to do it, thanks !

Comment: What do you mean by "only ONE user row"? If the `JOIN` produces mutliple rows, you will receive multiple rows.

Comment: @NicoHaase , I don't want duplicate user name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I have still all my progression.id + progressions.axis + progressions.topic_id rows but have only ONE user row ?

SQL is not really suitable for your purpose. Like spreadsheet programs, it deals exclusively in rectangular arrays of data.

You could try using [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) something like this.

```sql
SELECT users.id, users.lastname, users.firstname,
       GROUP_CONCAT(progressions.id ORDER BY progressions.id) ids,
       GROUP_CONCAT(progressions.axis ORDER BY progressions.id) axes,
       GROUP_CONCAT(progressions.topic_id ORDER BY progressions.id) topic_ids
FROM `progressions`
JOIN topics on topics.id = progressions.topic_id
JOIN criteria on criteria.id = topics.criteria_id
JOIN cards on cards.id = criteria.card_id
JOIN users on users.id = cards.user_id;
GROUP BY users.id, users.lastname, users.firstname;
```

But you still may end up with some duplicates depending on the 1:1 or 1:many relationships between your five tables.